# How do I keep a hover state active when I mouseover another element?

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I have a row of thumbnails like in Netflix and I have an information popover with links to relevant pages. The popover is absolutely positioned and generates content based on which thumbnail I mouse over.

I want the popover to stay visible if I move my over it from the thumb, but disappear if I move my mouse elsewhere away from the thumbnail.

```
$('.video-thumbs li').hover(

  function(){
      var posLeft = $(this).offset().left;
      var posMid = posLeft + $(this).width()/2;
      var posTop = $(this).offset().top;
      var popoverID = $(this).find('.video-info');
      var popContent = popoverID.html();

      if (posMid > w2) {
          posLeft -= 468;
      }

// Above is all positioning stuff

      setTimeout(function(){
          $('.popovertest').css({   //popovertest is the popover div
              'left': (posLeft + 185) + 'px',
              'top': (posTop - 25) + 'px',
              'transition': 'opacity 0.3s',
              'opacity': 1
          }).html(popContent);
      }, 100);

  }, function(){
      $('.popovertest').css({
        'transition': 0,
        'opacity': 0,
      });
});
```

I can't make the popover a child element unfortunately or I would.

Here is a jsfiddle of basically what I'm talking about  http://jsfiddle.net/gap_stuth/4mpsusq2/

Comment: Please try to provide any jsfiddle or sth with HTML to reproduce the problem

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/gap_stuth/4mpsusq2/

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mpsusq2/2/)

Mainly update code:

```
 $('.video-thumbs ul').hover(function (){},function (){ $('.popovertest').hide(200)})
```

And css attribute of class **popovertest**

```
 pointer-events:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` in jquery as follows:

```
 .active { background: #eee; }

 $('.video-thumbs ul').mouseover(function (){
   $(this).addClass("active");
 });

 $('.video-thumbs ul').mouseout(function (){
   $(this).removeClass("active");
 });
```